# "response code: 502" using socket.io and nginx 1.4.x (stable) with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I am trying to make running my app (using socket.io) under nginx, and i get an `WebSocket connection to 'ws://...' failed: Unexpected response code: 502` error on the server side.
I have read that nginx suport the websockets since the `v.1.3` so i just have upgrade to the nginx `v1.4.1 (stable)`.

Here is my conf:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name website.com;

        location / {
          proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          access_log    /var/log/nginx/website/access.log;
          error_log    /var/log/nginx/website/error.log;
        }
}
```

UPDATE:

I have to say that i can reach the app (so i do listen the port 3000) and socket.io is working unless this error, but in some cases, the `emit` call desn't send any arguments so i get `undefined`.

What am i missing here to avoid this error?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Are you getting anything in either the access or error logs regarding the requests?

Comment: Is your app listening on port 3000? Getting a 502 makes me think it's not running.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Thanks for replying, i was trying to consult my access/error log files but my `website` folder is empty. however the syntax looks good...

Comment: @Bart yes it does, i am using socket.io and express on the same port (v3.x) and i can reach the app, plus, socket.io also does work, but in some cases, i can't transmit any arguments on my `emit` calls

Comment: I have the same issues placing Node under Nginx. Firstly, some requests' arguments are undefined when they arrive to Node. And finally, i'm getting 502 error when i try to reach my Node app from outside, going throughout Nginx. If i get any solution or just fix the problem, i'll post it out here.

Answer (score -1):

I have found something to avoid this error:

`io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);`

So socket.io does now AJAX calls, it does the job but certainly a way much more slowly, so if someone has the real key to this issue i am still very interested!

Comment: This "fix" is simply not using web sockets.